# ForeignKey Field in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

There are around 1.5 lakhs entry in User model. So when i am using it in django-admin without the raw_id_fields it is causing problem while loading all the entry as a select menu of foreign key.
is there alternate way so that it could be loaded easily or could become searchable.

Basically i have these models as of defined above and there is a User model which is used as ForeignKey in ProfileRecommendation models. so the database entry for user model consist of around 1,50,000 entries. I don't want default select option for these foreign fields. Instead if can filter them out and load only few entries of the user table. Or anyhow i can make them searchable like autocomplete suggestion

#### admin.py

```
class ProfileRecommendationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'recommended_by', 'recommended_text')
    raw_id_fields = ("user", 'recommended_by')
    search_fields = ['user__username', 'recommended_by__username', ]
    admin.site.register(ProfileRecommendation, ProfileRecommendationAdmin)
```

#### models.py

```
class ProfileRecommendation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recommendations')
    recommended_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recommended')
    recommended_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    recommended_text = models.TextField(default='')
```

Comment: PLS describe the problem and ask a clear Q

Comment: Basically i have these models as of defined above and there is a User model which is used as ForeignKey in ProfileRecommendation models.
so the database entry for user model consist of around 1,50,000 entries.
I don't want default select option for these foreign fields. Instead if can filter them out and load only few entries of the user table. Or anyhow i can make them searchable like autocomplete suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove the default select in ForeignKey Field of django admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497185/remove-the-default-select-in-foreignkey-field-of-django-admin)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using  [django-select2-forms](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-select2-forms)

Using that package, you can define your model foreign field as below:

```
from select2.fields import ForeignKey

class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  active = models.BooleanField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    author = ForeignKey(Author,
    limit_choices_to=models.Q(active=True),
    ajax=True,
    search_field='name',
    overlay="Choose an author...",
    js_options={
        'quiet_millis': 200,
    },
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In django admin this will load authors' names using ajax, which should work much faster than using default admin ForeignKey field. Also as you can see from example, you can use **limit_choices_to** for filtering only needed values available for selection.

If not django-select2-forms, you can play with any other package available for django autocomplete: [list of autocomplete packages here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/)

I tried few from the list, but django-select2-forms looks like the best for me.